# Alternative to SELECT ... FOR UPDATE row locking with outer joins

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to achieve some way of `FOR UPDATE` locking rows returned in a `LEFT JOIN`. Postgresql does not support combining `FOR UPDATE` with an other join, since in the case of null rows it has nothing to lock on.

In my current query I had thought it would be enough to just lock on table `TableA` in a subquery, and left join in table `TableB` outside of it. The query runs, but it seems that postgresql fetches the rows from the `LEFT JOIN` regardless of whether the lock on the rows in table `TableA` could be obtained or not.

My current query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT j.correlation_id, j.current_state
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM "Db"."TableA" WHERE "correlation_id" = @p0 FOR UPDATE
    ) AS j
    LIMIT 2
) AS t
LEFT JOIN "Db"."TableB" AS j0 ON t.correlation_id = j0.correlation_id
ORDER BY t.correlation_id
```

So, while Alice is currently running this query and holding the lock in her transaction, Bob tries to execute the same query. The result seems to be that Bob immediately fetches the data specified in the `LEFT JOIN`, and *then* waits for the `FOR UPDATE` lock to release.

Ideally I would want the rows in the `JOIN` to be locked as well, but at the very least the data from the `JOIN` should be fetched *after* the `FOR UPDATE` lock has been obtained.

Comment: I would imagine that at `Serializable` isolation level, it will take a range lock preventing a new row being inserted. Have you tried changing the isolation level?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I imagine that `Serializable` would remove the need for `FOR UPDATE` entirely, but ideally I want to avoid that in order to minimize retrys in the calling code. Ideally I would like to keep the nice "wait for your turn" behaviour of `FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want to lock exactly. The `LIMIT 2` without `ORDER BY` makes the result arbitrary. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And your version of Postgres, obviously.